# Unity 8 won't boot

Tags: unity8, 17.04

I recently updated to Ubuntu 17.04, and I wanted to try out Unity 8. However when I try to boot it all I get is a black screen and it has in the past prevented the whole system from booting, I had to boot into recovery mode to get into my files. Please advise on what has gone wrong with Unity 8 and any possible fixes.